# Is it possible to prevent copy/move(drag and drop on web application) image across the web application?

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to prevent the drag and drop(Move/Copy) image or any file on across the web application.

for ex: I have open my web application and selected a system image and dropping into that web application, it is opening an image in full size and showing the url as file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg

I want to prevent it.

Is it possible if yes then how any JS, if no then whats the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).bind({
 dragenter: function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
 dt.effectAllowed = dt.dropEffect = 'none';
},
dragover: function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
  dt.effectAllowed = dt.dropEffect = 'none';
}
});
```

check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/andreymir/H3RR7/light/

Answer (score 0):

The onbeforeunload event is fired when the user tries to leave the current page. I tested it on Chrome, Firefox and IE 9 - it fires also if the user drops a file into the window. So this could be working for you. This depends on Javascript obviously which isn't guaranteed to be enabled. So don't rely on it.

E.g. with jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
        return 'Really leave page?';
    });
});
```

It will also fire if the user navigates away from the page, so this might be a bit inconvenient in practice.

Comment: I already tried it but its really very inconvenient... I don't want to show any confirm or alert

Comment: Why would you want to prevent it anyway? Why is it a problem if the user drags an image into the browser?

Comment: its the client requirement :(

Comment: I feel with you :) If a user drags a file into the browser window the browser tries to open it just as if you were to enter a new URL. That is, this action won't have any relation to your application except that the page the user was on unloaded. Therefore, using onbeforeunload is the only thing you can use to react to this event.  You'll have to explain that to your client. Maybe you can find out what he really wants. The general rule of thumb: you cannot guarantee anything that's happening on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the following code in the head of your HTML document, that is, between the  tags.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
<!-- Disable 
function disableselect(e){ 
return false 
} 

function reEnable(){ 
return true 
} 

//if IE4+ 
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false") 
document.oncontextmenu=new Function ("return false") 
//if NS6 
if (window.sidebar){ 
document.onmousedown=disableselect 
document.onclick=reEnable 
} 
//--> 
</script>
```